# What is the difference between = and == in R?

Tags: r, syntax, r-faq

What is the difference between `=` and `==`? I have found cases where the double equal sign will allow my script to run while one equal sign produces an error message. When should I use `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is a logical comparison

Comment: The are also help pages if you ever get stuck. `help("=")` and  `and help("==")`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on context as to what `=` means. `==` is always for testing equality.

`=` can be

1. ***in most cases*** used as a drop-in replacement for `<-`, the assignment operator.

   ```
   > x = 10
   > x
   [1] 10
   ```
2. used as the separator for key-value pairs used to assign values to arguments in function calls.

   ```
   rnorm(n = 10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
   ```

Because of 2. above, `=` can't be used as a drop-in replacement for `<-` in all situations. Consider

```
> rnorm(N <- 10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
 [1] 4.893132 4.572640 3.801045 3.646863 4.522483 4.881694 6.710255 6.314024
 [9] 2.268258 9.387091
> rnorm(N = 10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
Error in rnorm(N = 10, mean = 5, sd = 2) : unused argument (N = 10)
> N
[1] 10
```

Now some would consider `rnorm(N <- 10, mean = 5, sd = 2)` poor programming, but it is valid and you need to be aware of the differences between `=` and `<-` for assignment.

`==` is always used for equality testing:

```
> set.seed(10)
> logi <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
> logi
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> logi == TRUE
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> seq.int(1, 10) == 5L
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Do be careful with `==` too however, as it really means exactly equal to and on a computer where floating point operations are involved you may not get the answer you were expecting. For example, from `?'=='`:

```
> x1 <- 0.5 - 0.3
> x2 <- 0.3 - 0.1
> x1 == x2                           # FALSE on most machines
[1] FALSE
> identical(all.equal(x1, x2), TRUE) # TRUE everywhere
[1] TRUE
```

where `all.equal()` tests for equality allowing for a little bit of fuzziness due to loss of precision/floating point operations.

Comment: I assume that the question arises because of the subset and similar functions: 

Say that whe have a dataset with countries being one of the columns "Continents". Teh code below would return an ampty data.frame: 


```
Asia <- subset(countries, Continents == "Asia")
```
this code would however do the right thing: 

```
Asia <- subset(countries, Continents = "Asia")
```

Answer (score 7):

`=` is basically a synonym for assignment ( `<-` ), but most often used when passing values into functions.

`==` is a test for equality

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest of terms, take these two lines of code for example:

1) x = 10
2) x == 10

The first line (x = 10) means "I am commanding that x is equal to 10."

The second line (x == 10) means "I am asking the question, is x equal to 10?"

If you write "x == 10" first, it will give you an error message and tell you that x is not found.

If you write "x = 10," this will store x as 10.

After you have written "x = 10", then if you write "x == 10," it will respond "TRUE", as in "yes, x does equal 10, because you made x equal to 10." But if you write "x == 11" or "x == 12" or x == anything besides 10, then it will respond that "FALSE," as in "no, x does not equal 11 or 12 or anything besides 10, because you made x equal to 10."

Answer (score 0):

- (=) is a **Assignment** operator while (==) is a **Equal to** operator.
- (=) is used for assigning the values from right to left while (==) is used for showing equality between values.

Example:

```
$test = 1;
if($test=2){
echo "Hello";
}

if($test==2){
echo "world";
}
//The result is Hello because = is assigning the value to $test and the second condition is false because it check the equality of $test to the value 2.
```

I hope this will help.