# Compare to df's and populate col based on matching rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two df's that look like this,

```
id1<-c(2,2,2,1,3)
id2<-c(4,4,5,2,3)
OS<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
a <- cbind(OS, id1, id2) 
a
```

```
i1<-c(2,2,2,4,3)
i2<-c(4,4,5,2,3)
OSi<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- cbind(OSi, i1, i2)
```

I want to create a new col (x) with a '0' where a$OS & a$OSi match (i.e. 1->1, 2->2) but only where the subsequent two cols in each df are in agreement, and '1' where they don't.
My desired output is something like this:

```
id1<-c(2,2,2,1,3)
id2<-c(4,4,5,2,3)
OS<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x <-c(0,0,0,1,0)
a <- cbind(OS, id1, id2, x) 
a
```

I have so far tried this:

```
a$x <- case_when(a$OS %in% b$OSi &
                     a$id1 %in% b$I1 & 
                     b$id2 %in% b$I2 ~ '0') %>%
  replace_na('1')
```

However, I find that Case_when only looks to satisfy the first argument here. (i.e. the ratio of 0/1 change depending on the order of the variables).

Also, the above is a top df. My actual data is ~10000 rows and b is longer than a. I may also want to drop any rows not in a, but in b.

I hope that's clear enough.
Dplyr my preference to integrate into pipes!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> id1<-c(2,2,2,1,3)
> id2<-c(4,4,5,2,3)
> OS<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
> a <- data.frame(OS, id1, id2) 
> 
> 
> i1<-c(2,2,2,4,3)
> i2<-c(4,4,5,2,3)
> OSi<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
> b <- data.frame(OSi, i1, i2) 
> 
> 
> transform(a %>% inner_join(b, by = c('OS' = 'OSi')), x = ifelse((id1 == i1) & (id2 == i2), 0, 1)) %>% select(OS, id1, id2, x)
  OS id1 id2 x
1  1   2   4 0
2  2   2   4 0
3  3   2   5 0
4  4   1   2 1
5  5   3   3 0
>
```

I used inner_join, so we are joining based on your first condition of a$OS == b$OSi

Comment: I don't think I can bind the df's because they're different lengths:
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7625, 8996

Comment: OK, assumed so from your sample data. So, do OS and OSi overlap ? Can they be used as primary key and foreign key in that case? If so, which is your primary table, I am assuming it's "a" ?

Comment: Have changed the code, can you please check if that works?

Comment: Hi Karthik, thanks for this, but it doesn't quite work.
I'm not sure why, but it gives me fewer positive (1) results than I expect.

Comment: OK, can you please include the parts where you are not getting expected output to your sample data above? With just 5 rows in sample data, it may be difficult to visualize the issue.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how I can write this expression:

p$EP <- case_when(p$BroodName %in% broods$Brood & 
                     p$sire %in% broods$SocialDadID &
                    p$dam %in% broods$SocialMumID ~ 'N') %>%
  replace_na('Y')

(from my actual data), where the case_when considers the '&', rather than only listening to the first argument.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137828/create-new-variable-by-multiple-conditions-via-mutate-case-when seems to imply the '&' is considered in Case_when?