# ifelse function in R to create a new variable

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I created a new variable "house_group" in my dataset filenamed "adoption". I want entries in "house_group" to be 0 or 1 based on a condition: If education (another variable in the dataset) is 1, house_group should be 1. But if education is 2, house_group should be 0. I used following ifelse function. But it returns NA for the new variable house_group. The options in variable "education" are 1 and 2, and they are categorical not continuous. I want House_group options 1 and 0 as categorical. Any help?

```
adoption$house_group<-NA

ifelse(adoption$education=="1",adoption$house_group=="1", adoption$house_group=="0")

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [32] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [63] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [94] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[125] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[156] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[187] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[218] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[249] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[280] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[311] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[342] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[373] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[404] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[435] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[466] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[497] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I did. didnt work. These are categorical variables and options are characters. 1 means yes, 0 means no in house_group. 1 means literate and 2 means not in education variable.

Comment: `==` does comparison, `=` does assignment. You've got 3 comparisons made inside your `ifelse` call. I'd recommend looking at the docs for the syntax `ifelse` uses; it should be `adoption$house_group <- ifelse(adoption$education == "1", "1", "0")` or something similar

Comment: See [`=` vs `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28176650/5325862)

Comment: Thanks @camille. works

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve this using data.frame masking. Selecting the correct rows and column you want and then replacing those NA's in groups.

```
df <- as.data.frame(sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c('education')
df$house_group <- NA
df[df$education == 1,'house_group'] <- 1
df[df$education == 2,'house_group'] <- 0
```

Another way using your ifelse logic. The problem being that you aren't using the assignment operator "<-" in your ifelse function above.

```
df$house_group <- ifelse(df$education=="1", 1, 0)
```

Comment: could we use ifelse function or statement, instead? any clue?

Comment: ifelse(df$education==1,df$house_group <- 1, df$house_group <- 0)

You might need to change your education variable into an int using as.integer()

Comment: the problem in your code about is you're not *assigning* the variable to be 1 or 0 in the house group section with <-, you were using == which is a binary operator to check if things are equal, not to assign

Comment: You don't need to do assignment inside the `ifelse` function, since it will return a vector that you assign to `df$house_group`. This syntax seems like it could be error-prone anyway

Comment: made the edits, ty

Comment: It partially solves the questions. While house_group changes from NA to 1 and 0, when I do summary or table it shows all 0 only:

Comment: Did you assign it back to the dataframe over the old house group column or as a new column?

Comment: > adoption$house_group<-NA: > as.numeric(adoption$education)
> ifelse(adoption$education==1,adoption$house_group<-1, adoption$house_group<-0)
> table(adoption$house_group)
  0 
510

Comment: That works  @devinbrowndev. Thanks so much!

Comment: as.numeric(adoption$education) 

This line is not assigning the result to memory. You are just running it, you'll need to assign it as follows adoption$education <- as.numeric(adoption$education)