# For loop with variables in quotation mark

Tags: r

I want to subset my object `object`  based on names in by object, and plot each subset. The subsetting is defined in `idents` like for example `idents ="T-cell"` and need to be specified with quotes. How do I set the quotes from the for-loop=?

```
for (i in names(table(Idents(object))))
{
subset.out <- subset(x = object, idents = "i") #i there is the problem
DimPlot(subset.out)
}
```

My solution in the end:

```
ids <- names(table(Idents(object)))

for (i in 1:length(celltypes)) {
  subset.out <- subset(x = object, idents =ids[i])
  print(DimPlot(subset.out))
}
```

Comment: as you are using foreach, why don't you try `subset(object, idents == i)` note that it is `==` and `i` is not quoted

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28176650/3358272 (`=` versus `==`).