# Why not single = in dplyr::filter

Tags: r, filter

Sorry for that question against a convention. The single `=` in `filter()` is the most common error made by me and my students. One of my students asked me, what the single equal sign is needed for in `filter()` other than comparing. We both understand, that in other contexts the `=` is used to define a variable or an object. Her argument is, that in `filter()`, the error handler always say `probably you forgot to write two ==` So why could `filter()` not accept both? The absolute correct `==` and in context of `filter()` unambiguous `=`?

I‘m asking for the argument. So this question is meant as a question and not a suggestion!  :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176650/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: R exclusively uses `==` as the logical operator. It goes back a long time and I think would be inconsistent with the design philosophy/tradition of R or the tidyverse to make a change as substantial as that.

Comment: `?filter` tells us that the second argument has to be "expressions that return a logical value" _i.e._ TRUE or FALSE. Only comparison operators do this, not assignment operators. A human might think that "=" is unambiguous in the context of `filter`, but the R language isn't designed that way.

Comment: Ok, it‘s tradition and philosophy and logical. My students are more familiar with the double interpretation (assignment and logical) of the single equal sign from SPSS and Excel. I will tell them, that R is cleaner and a bit stricter by tradition.

Comment: Also, even if `=` were interpreted as an equality check by `filter()`, it could not be equivalent to `==` in this context. That's because `=` is actually passing a named argument to the function. If the left hand side is not a name but an expression (e.g. trying to do `max(x) = x`), that's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is that dplyr::filter is requiring using “==“ to test a logical statement in order to properly filter, and that the code doesn’t work with an assignment operator (“=“ or “<-“ which are equivalent in R). Having multiple definitions for “=“ would cause too much confusion in R in my opinion.

Comment: Good point! On the other hand, we use the + for sums and the pipe in ggplot. ;-)

Comment: That is a great example! In reading about this awhile back, I came across this question and post on the rstudio blog, check out Hadley’s reply on the ‘+’ and lack of the Magrittr pipe in ggplot : thought it was interesting and hope you do as well <https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-cant-ggplot2-use/4372/4>